# Same Add-in comamnd does not work on second workbook in Excel for Mac

Tags: office-js

I ran into a issue while developing a office-js solution for Excel for Mac. I am using Excel for Mac Version 15.35 (170517).  It seems any Add-in command button which executes a function does not work on the second workbook after it is executed on the first workbook.  Below are the steps to reproduce this bug.

1. Create a manifest which adds a button to the Home tab in Excel.  Make the button call a function which sets "Hello World" in the selected cell.
2. Side load the manifest into Excel for Mac.
3. Start Excel, go to Insert tab and select the manifest created on step one from the drop down next to "My Add-ins"
4. After the add-in is loaded, go to Home tab, and click on the button created by the manifest.
5. "Hello World" is displayed on the selected cell.
6. Open a new workbook.
7. Go to Home tab, and click on the button created by the manifest again.
8. Instead of seeing "Hello World" on the selected cell, nothing happens.

Comment: Hi George, first welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you mind updating the question and copying the html and js codes there? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug of Office.js. We succeeded reproducing this it. It only happens on Mac.

Thanks for reporting.

We will fix it in the future version.

If someone else wants to reproduce, the code is

**FunctionFile.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="FunctionFile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**FunctionFile.js**

```
(function () {
    Office.initialize = function (reason) { };
})();

function SetData(event) {    
    Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync("Hello World!",
        function (asyncResult) {
            var error = asyncResult.error;            
    });    
    event.completed();
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Please let me know when it is fixed.